# Output multiple text files from PCollection<KV<String, String>>

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

How do I output to multiple files from `PCollection<KV<String, String>>`?

The key in each entry is the file name. The groupByKey transformation gives me `PCollection<KV<String, Iterable<String>>>`, but how I can write them to multiple files?

For example, given the following input

```
<file1, value1>
<file2, value2>
<file1, value3>
```

I'd like to output two files

```
file1:
  value1
  value3

file2:
  value2
```

Comment: This is available now, via TextIO.write().to(DynamicDestinations). See https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.java#L571

Answer (score 2):

Dataflow currently does not have a transform that can do this for you. As a work-around, you can do this using a simple `DoFn` that will extract the filename from the `KV`, open the file using `IOChannelFactory`, and write the `Iterable<String>` to it.

See [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29147057/how-to-output-all-values-from-a-key-value-pair-grouped-by-key-using-google-d?rq=1) and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35979421/dynamic-table-name-when-writing-to-bq-from-dataflow-pipelines?rq=1).

We have plans to address this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-92, but no concrete timeline yet.